# 'PAGE NOT FOUND' I have an error when creating index.vue on Nuxt3, any idea?

Tags: nuxt3

Hi guys i follow the docs for creates the `/pages` on my Nuxt3 App, at first i created the paging version with `App.vue` like this:

```
<template>
   <div>
     <NuxtPage />
   </div>
</template>
```

and on `pages/` i created the `index.vue`

at twice i created the alternative version without `App.vue` but i have the same error.

On browser seems everything works fine, on terminal i have this error:

```
ℹ Vite client warmed up in 1490ms                                               22:04:31
✔ Nitro built in 349 ms                                                   nitro 22:04:31
✔ Vite server hmr 17 files in 1198.848ms                                        22:04:33
[nuxt] error caught during app initialization H3Error: Page not found: /robots.txt?1678050273812
    at Module.createError (file:///Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/node_modules/h3/dist/index.mjs:128:15)
    at /Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/node_modules/nuxt/dist/pages/runtime/plugins/router.mjs:141:113
    at triggerAfterEach (file:///Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:3306:13)
    at file:///Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/node_modules/vue-router/dist/vue-router.mjs:3209:13
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async /Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/node_modules/nuxt/dist/pages/runtime/plugins/router.mjs:157:7
    at async createNuxtAppServer (/Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/node_modules/nuxt/dist/app/entry.mjs:30:7)
    at async default (file:///Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/node_modules/@nuxt/vite-builder/dist/runtime/vite-node.mjs:27:18)
    at async Object.renderToString (file:///Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/node_modules/vue-bundle-renderer/dist/runtime.mjs:172:19)
    at async file:///Users/marcoguglielmino/Documents/GinTonic_Nuxt3/gintonic_nuxi/.nuxt/dev/index.mjs:717:21 {
  statusCode: 404,
  fatal: false,
  unhandled: false,
  statusMessage: 'Page not found: /robots.txt?1678050273812',
  __nuxt_error: true
}
```

i tried to reinstall nuxt3 and retry every steps following the official docs, but nothing changes, someone can help me?

as i said before the structure of my app in this moment follows the official patters that you can find on Nuxt3's official docs, with `pages/.index.vue`

Comment: Based on the given error, it is not related to the `pages` folder. The issue is the `robot.txt` file. It does not exist that is why it is throwing an error.